# Amazon SNS mobile push: send message to a specific user

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm using SNS with a mobile app. Is it possible with Amazon SNS to send a message only to a particular user. For example only to the user that has some unread messages?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Publish API call's target_arn parameter can be either a topic, or directly a device, so yes.

Comment: Thank you...I didn't see it.